# Why by enumtype dynamic="false" is set to false?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, hybris-data-hub

Why by enumtype `dynamic="false"` is set to false? And when should I set it to `"true"`?

```
<enumtype code="MyEnumType" generate="true" autocreate="true" dynamic="false">
    <value code="NONE" />
    <value code="ONE" />
</enumtype>
```

Comment: For complete comprehension and up to date information you should just check the official documentation : https://help.hybris.com/6.7.0/hcd/8c895989866910148d6a802f06651702.html. Also in this case just reading the xsd from your code editor would provide you the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple words, I can say static enum(`dynamic="false"`, default value) is generated as the Java enum. In which list of values can only be changed during compilation time by changing the items.xml. In case of the dynamic enum(`dynamic="true"`) we can change(add/remove) its values at runtime using hmc or Impex.

---

### Static Enum:

```
    <enumtype code="FixedValueType" autocreate="true" generate="true">
        <value code="value1"/>
        <value code="value2"/>
    </enumtype>
```

### Dynamic Enum:

```
    <enumtype code="OrderStatus" autocreate="true" generate="true" dynamic="true">
        <value code="CREATED"/>
        <value code="ON_VALIDATION"/>
        <value code="COMPLETED"/>
        <value code="CANCELLED"/>
    </enumtype>
```

---

### [more about hybris enum](https://www.helphybris.com/2018/04/hybris-enumtype-static-vs-dynamic.html)

Answer (score 2):

With the hybris enumtype, you have the option to define a static enum or a dynamic enum. Static (dynamic="false") means, that the enumeration only contains the defined elements. During runtime you will never be able to add elements to the enum. This is different when you use a dynamic enum (dynamic="true"). With dynamic enumerations you can add values during runtime. So if you want your enum to be static, use dynamic="false". If you want to add values during runtime, use dynamic="true".

Answer (score 1):

I think i found the answer on a hard way:

```
INSERT_UPDATE ManufacturerName;code[unique=true];name[lang=de];name[lang=en]

    ,,,,Exception : line 9: cannot create ManufacturerName with values ItemAttributeMap[ registry:  null, type: <null>, data: {code=00000023344, name={8796093054536->de=3D , 8796093054536->en=3D }} ] due to [de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.interceptor.impl.EnumerationValidator@197d511d]:Enum type ManufacturerName is not dynamic - can not create new enum value 00000023344. If you want to add a new value to this type you have to define the enum type as non dynamic at items.xml (needs system update afterwards).
```

Answer (score 0):

If `dynamic ="false"`, it means it acts as `java_Enum` (it cannot be modified).

If `dynamic ="true"`, it acts as `hybris_Enum` (i.e, you will able to add the additional Enumeration value `Types` at runtime through hac).